# testing the contents of a list using another list

Tags: python, list, for-loop

so i am programming in python and i have two lists one named validurls, and another named used
here is the code that is failing me:

```
for i in range(len(validurls[i])):
    for bb in range(len(used[bb])):
        if validurls[i] == used[bb]:
            o = 0
        else:
            used.append(validurls[i])
```

so what I am doing is: "validurls" fetches some urls for me, then i want it to throw in the new urls into "used" using used.append(validurls[i]), But i do not want repeat urls in used. Is there anyway to do this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're going to want to use `in` for this:

```py
array_one = [<your array>]
array_two = [<your other array>]

for entry in array_one:
  if entry not in array_two:
    array_two.append(entry)
```

What this does is check if each entry in your first array is in your second array, and if it is not, it injects it into the second array. This will take all the content of the first array which is unique, and add it to the second.

Answer (score 1):

You're probably better off using a `set` for these instead of a `list` since they enforce uniqueness on their own and make the combination very easy:

```
In [149]: validurls = {'a', 'b', 'c', 'd'}

In [150]: used = {'c', 'd', 'e'}

In [151]: used |= validurls

In [152]: used
Out[152]: {'a', 'b', 'c', 'd', 'e'}
```